# Dynamically changing std::set by intersection

Tags: c++, dynamic, reference, set, std

I'm writing the function

```
void update(set<int> &dynamic, const set<int> &compare){
    set<int> res_set;
    set_intersection(dynamic.begin(), dynamic.end(), compare.begin(), compare.end(),
        std::inserter(res_set, res_set.end()));
    dynamic = res_set;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if this essentially makes a copy of `res_set` first, then assigns it to `dynamic` (which would be inefficient), or whether it just assigns the variable `dynamic` to `res_set` already stored in memory (which is efficient and what I want). I don't want to copy a set, which may have an extremely large number of elements inside, making the whole program slower.

My goal is to be able to efficiently change `dynamic` as I call the function by passing many different `set<int>`s into `compare` (this will make pruning paths on a search tree much more efficient).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sets aren't the fastest things in the universe to begin with. If performance is really a problem, sorted vectors with unique elements are faster, but obviously harder to maintain.

Comment: Why don't you simply return the set? Using `std::move()` that should be reasonably fast and perfectly readable, too. If you're stuck with ancient C++, use the `swap()` function to replace without copying. Alternatively, rewrite your algorithm to modify the target set in-place. Lastly, I think there was an algorithm coming from the STL that does what this sounds like...

Comment: You have to re-implement `set_intersection` logic to remove element in place.

Answer (score 0):

Step an iterator through each of the two sets in parallel, i.e. in a single `for` loop that increments one or both iterators on each cycle.  Whenever you notice that the currently pointed-to item from `dynamic`, which I'll call `d`, is less than the currently pointed-to item from `compare`, which I'll call `c`, it can only mean that `d` is absent from `compare` -- so you should then delete it from `dynamic`, and advance the iterator for `dynamic`.  Whenever you notice that `d > c`, you should advance the iterator for `compare` (in this case you don't perform any deletion, because you want to leave `compare` unchanged).  Whenever `d == c`, advance both iterators.  This works because `std::set<T>`'s iterators access elements in increasing order -- you're essentially performing a list merge.

Provided you obtain the next value of the iterator *before* performing the deletion, this is safe, because the C++ standard guarantees that deleting items from a `std::set<T>` cannot invalidate any other iterators.  And it's efficient: if the lengths of `dynamic` and `compare` are m and n respectively, it will take time O(m + n).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this what `set_intersection` is doing with two sets? Can I just use that function in some clever way, or must I implement this myself? If I need to implement myself, can you possibly give an example?

Comment: `set_intersection` is doing something conceptually similar -- it will involve the same, single loop that steps through both containers -- but it is inserting new elements instead of deleting existing elements, so you can't use it to modify an existing `std::set<T>` in-place.